# MATLAB save iteratively to struct

Tags: matlab, vector, struct, save, iteration

**MATLAB save iteratively to struct**
1) Running a function 
2) Each output [vectorA, vectorB], which are vectors of different sizes, should be save in each iteration i in the struct

But this sytax doesn´t work:

```
for i=1:n
    [vectorA, vectorB] = anyfunction(i)
    myStruct(i).vectorA = {[vectorA]};
    myStruct(i).vectorB = {[vectorB]};
end
```

Comment: Can you post the syntax error message, or say what you expected?

Comment: @Cyborg: Thanks for editing! Synatax works, it was just a readout problem: Better do not put {[]} around the vectors. Just leave them as they are. Thanks

Comment: @alex: I added an answer, but then recognized that your syntax actually works, with or without {[]}, so I deleted it. So what is the problem? Show us what error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
n=5;
anyfunction=@(x) eig(magic(x));

for i=1:n
    [vectorA, vectorB] = anyfunction(i);
    myStruct(i).vectorA = vectorA;
    myStruct(i).vectorB = vectorB;
end

myStruct = 

1x5 struct array with fields:
    vectorA
    vectorB
```